# Groupby one column and compare monthly, quarterly mixed data's current period values with previous using R

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidyverse

Assuming I have a panel data as follows, which was edited from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70750279/filter-columns-and-repeatedly-comparing-two-columns-in-pair-using-r):

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("M01", 
"M02", "S01"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("2020-12", "2021-01", "2021-02", 
"2021-03", "2021-04", "2021-05", "2021-06", "2021-07"), class = "factor"), 
    actual = c(3.4, 5.4, 7.4, 7.4, 7.5, 8, 8.9, 10.8, 10.1, 8.2, 
    10.1, 9.4, 10.1, 9.4, -0.3, NA, NA, 8.6, NA, NA, 8.3, NA), 
    pred = c(3.288889774, 5.819407687, 6.705608369, 6.054457292, 
    5.582409131, 7.01052472, 9.742902434, 10.98571396, 6.522003651, 
    9.688977242, 10.39801463, 9.398991615, 9.764616936, 9.855033457, 
    0.493311422, 8.403722942, 8.174854517, 8.573117852, 8.403065801, 
    8.684289455, 8.719079247, 8.259439468)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

After groupby `id`, for each month's actual and predicted values, I need to check if current month's actual and predicted values with same directions comparing to previous month's actual values. The logic of creating new columns is: if the difference values of two months' are `positive`, `negative` or `zero`s, then return `increase`, `decrease` and `unchanged` respectively, if either or both of values are `NA`s, then return `NA`.

```
df %>% 
  # mutate(year = as.integer(year)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  # arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(act_direction = case_when(actual > lag(actual) ~ "increase",
                                   actual < lag(actual) ~ "decrease",
                                   actual == lag(actual) ~ "unchanged"),
         pred_direction = case_when(pred > lag(actual) ~ "increase",
                                    pred < lag(actual) ~ "decrease",
                                    pred == lag(actual) ~ "unchanged"))
```

If all `id` are monthly data, the code above works smoothly. But for this example, we will have exception: let's say for `id=='S01'`, it's a quarterly data instead of monthly, so I'll need compare values ie., in `2021-03`'s with `2020-12`'s instead of `2021-02`, same logic for other months.

How could I modify the code to coordinate with this case? Thanks.

The expected outcome:

```
    id    date actual       pred act_direction pred_direction
1  M01 2021-01    3.4  3.2888898                             
2  M01 2021-02    5.4  5.8194077      increase       increase
3  M01 2021-03    7.4  6.7056084      increase       increase
4  M01 2021-04    7.4  6.0544573     unchanged       decrease
5  M01 2021-05    7.5  5.5824091      increase       decrease
6  M01 2021-06    8.0  7.0105247      increase       decrease
7  M01 2021-07    8.9  9.7429024      increase       increase
8  M02 2021-01   10.8 10.9857140                             
9  M02 2021-02   10.1  6.5220037      decrease       decrease
10 M02 2021-03    8.2  9.6889772      decrease       decrease
11 M02 2021-04   10.1 10.3980146      increase       increase
12 M02 2021-05    9.4  9.3989916      decrease       decrease
13 M02 2021-06   10.1  9.7646169      increase       increase
14 M02 2021-07    9.4  9.8550335      decrease       decrease
15 S01 2020-12   -0.3  0.4933114                             
16 S01 2021-01     NA  8.4037229                             
17 S01 2021-02     NA  8.1748545                             
18 S01 2021-03    8.6  8.5731179      increase       increase  # compare with S01's actual value in 2020-12
19 S01 2021-04     NA  8.4030658                             
20 S01 2021-05     NA  8.6842895                             
21 S01 2021-06    8.3  8.7190792      decrease       increase  # compare with S01's actual value in 2021-03
22 S01 2021-07     NA  8.2594395
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a temporary `fill` and then remove the unwanted values by referring back to the original data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

chg <- c("decrease", "unchanged", "increase")

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(actual2=actual) %>% 
  fill(actual2) %>% 
  mutate(act_direction = case_when(
              actual2 > lag(actual2) ~ chg[3], 
              actual2 < lag(actual2) ~ chg[1], 
              actual2 == lag(actual2) ~ chg[2]), 
         pred_direction = case_when(
              pred > lag(actual2) ~ chg[3], 
              pred < lag(actual2) ~ chg[1], 
              pred == lag(actual2) ~ chg[2]), 
         act_direction=ifelse(is.na(actual),NA,act_direction),
         pred_direction=ifelse(is.na(actual),NA,pred_direction), actual2=NULL) %>%
  mutate(across(c(act_direction, pred_direction), replace_na, "")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  print(n=nrow(.))
A tibble: 22 × 6
 id    date    actual   pred act_direction pred_direction
 <fct> <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>         
 M01   2021-01    3.4  3.29  ""            ""            
 M01   2021-02    5.4  5.82  "increase"    "increase"    
 M01   2021-03    7.4  6.71  "increase"    "increase"    
 M01   2021-04    7.4  6.05  "unchanged"   "decrease"    
 M01   2021-05    7.5  5.58  "increase"    "decrease"    
 M01   2021-06    8    7.01  "increase"    "decrease"    
 M01   2021-07    8.9  9.74  "increase"    "increase"    
 M02   2021-01   10.8 11.0   ""            ""            
 M02   2021-02   10.1  6.52  "decrease"    "decrease"    
 M02   2021-03    8.2  9.69  "decrease"    "decrease"    
 M02   2021-04   10.1 10.4   "increase"    "increase"    
 M02   2021-05    9.4  9.40  "decrease"    "decrease"    
 M02   2021-06   10.1  9.76  "increase"    "increase"    
 M02   2021-07    9.4  9.86  "decrease"    "decrease"    
 S01   2020-12   -0.3  0.493 ""            ""            
 S01   2021-01   NA    8.40  ""            ""            
 S01   2021-02   NA    8.17  ""            ""            
 S01   2021-03    8.6  8.57  "increase"    "increase"    
 S01   2021-04   NA    8.40  ""            ""            
 S01   2021-05   NA    8.68  ""            ""            
 S01   2021-06    8.3  8.72  "decrease"    "increase"    
 S01   2021-07   NA    8.26  ""            ""
```

Answer (score 1):

data.table solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
v <- c('actual', 'pred')
df[!is.na(actual),
   (paste0(v,'_direction')) := lapply(.SD, function(x){
     return(case_when(
       x > lag(actual) ~ "increase",
       x < lag(actual) ~ "decrease",
       x == lag(actual) ~ "unchanged"
       )
       )
   }),
by = .(id),
.SDcols = v
]
print(df)

     id    date actual       pred actual_direction pred_direction
 1: M01 2021-01    3.4  3.2888898             <NA>           <NA>
 2: M01 2021-02    5.4  5.8194077         increase       increase
 3: M01 2021-03    7.4  6.7056084         increase       increase
 4: M01 2021-04    7.4  6.0544573        unchanged       decrease
 5: M01 2021-05    7.5  5.5824091         increase       decrease
 6: M01 2021-06    8.0  7.0105247         increase       decrease
 7: M01 2021-07    8.9  9.7429024         increase       increase
 8: M02 2021-01   10.8 10.9857140             <NA>           <NA>
 9: M02 2021-02   10.1  6.5220037         decrease       decrease
10: M02 2021-03    8.2  9.6889772         decrease       decrease
11: M02 2021-04   10.1 10.3980146         increase       increase
12: M02 2021-05    9.4  9.3989916         decrease       decrease
13: M02 2021-06   10.1  9.7646169         increase       increase
14: M02 2021-07    9.4  9.8550335         decrease       decrease
15: S01 2020-12   -0.3  0.4933114             <NA>           <NA>
16: S01 2021-01     NA  8.4037229             <NA>           <NA>
17: S01 2021-02     NA  8.1748545             <NA>           <NA>
18: S01 2021-03    8.6  8.5731179         increase       increase
19: S01 2021-04     NA  8.4030658             <NA>           <NA>
20: S01 2021-05     NA  8.6842895             <NA>           <NA>
21: S01 2021-06    8.3  8.7190792         decrease       increase
22: S01 2021-07     NA  8.2594395             <NA>           <NA>
     id    date actual       pred actual_direction pred_direction
```

Comment: Thanks, do u mind add comment to explain for `by = .(id), .SDcols = v`? I don't understand that part.

Comment: `by = .(id)`
It's the same as group_by in dplyr.  .() is same as list()

`.SDcols = v`
Telss which columns to use in .SD

Comment: I think filter by `NA` will not be suitable for the data with column `actual` back-filled, which means for `S01`, `2021-02` and `2021-01` will not be `NA`s, but same value as `2021-03`, at this case, maybe we need replace values by `NA` at first, then apply your code.